# Comment traduire « ein Blick in etwas » ?

Tags: traduction, choix-de-mot, allemand

Je dois traduire le texte suivant :

> XXX verfügt über eine sehr gute Marktposition.  Dies zeigt auch ein
>   Blick in unsere Referenzliste.

Voici mes efforts:

> XXX a une très bonne position sur le marché.  Cela se traduit également
>   par **un coup d'œil** à notre liste de références.

Est-ce qu'on peut dire ça ?
Cela semble-t-il correct ?

Mon collègue veut que je le traduise comme ceci :

> Cela se traduit également par **une consultation** de notre liste de
>   références.

Est-ce que c'est vraiment mieux ? Parce que je pense que c'est pire.
Qui a raison ?

Comment: Merci d'expliquer le sens de la phrase allemande : des lecteurs qui ne parlent pas allemand pourraient avoir des suggestions de formulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Coup d'œil* et *consultation* sont possibles. *Coup d'œil* ou *rapide coup d'œil* est un peu informel mais traduit mieux l'idée de brièveté.

> Un coup d’œil à notre liste de références le montre.

*La consultation* est plus formel et ne connote aucune notion de durée.

> La consultation de notre liste de références permet de le confirmer.

Cela ne marche que dans ce contexte. Je pense que l'expression est généralement difficile à traduire en français, il y a plusieurs traductions qui ne conviennent que dans des contextes particuliers. Par exemple « ein Blick in die Vergangenheit » peut se traduire « un regard dans le passé », pour l'avenir ce serait « un aperçu du futur », etc.

Answer (score 2):

Je comprends la phrase allemande comme signifiant ceci (mais je peux me tromper) :

« Un regard jeté sur notre liste de références montre également ceci. »

Si c'est bien le cas, voici quelques propositions de traduction :

« Ceci est [aussi] [nettement/clairement] visible sur notre liste de références. »
« Ceci est [aussi] [très] apparent sur notre liste de références. »
« Ceci se voit [aussi] [bien] sur notre liste de références. »
« Un [simple] regard sur notre liste de références le confirme. »

« Aussi » (ou « également ») traduit *auch*, mais je ne suis pas sûr que *auch* ait ici ce sens et non celui d'intensification. Il faudrait qu'une phrase précédente décrive un élément de preuve que XXX a une très bonne position sur le marché, ce qui ne semble pas être le cas. Dans « se voit [aussi] [bien] », on ne peut pas mettre à la fois *aussi* et *bien*, sinon les deux mots seraient interprétés comme formant un comparatif (*so gut wie*) qui n'a pas de sens ici.

« Clairement » insiste sur le fait qu'une lecture rapide de la liste de références laisse voir la position de XXX, il n'y a pas besoin d'une analyse poussée. « Nettement » renforce plutôt l'ampleur de la bonne position de XXX. Avec « apparent » ou « se voit », il n'y a pas de moyen léger d'exprimer cette nuance.